# add standard deviation to ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

DF is a data frame.
I would like to add standard deviation to the following plot

```
DF$conc_sig_lip <- as.factor(DF$conc_sig_lip)
p2 <-ggplot(DF[DF$conc_sig_lip != "NaN",], aes(x=conc_sig_lip, y=nbi, fill=conc_sig_lip)) + 
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="bar",show.legend = TRUE) +  
  theme_minimal()
p2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOvervlow. It is always helpful to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is, including some toy data. This way, others can test and adapt your code more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its most basic form, you could add another `stat_summary` for that:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  value = runif(n=100),
  group = sample(c('A','B','C'), size=100, replace=T)
) 

ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x=group)) +
  stat_summary(func="mean", geom="bar") +
  stat_summary(func="sd", geom="errorbar")
```

Which gives you something like [image: this]